# Solc installed ok but so solcjs command not found?

Tags: solidity, solc, npm, solcjs

I'm struggling for days with this. MacOs Monterey v12.2.1

npm install -g solc

works fine.
then when I try to use any solcjs command, it says :
zsh: command not found: solcjs

print screen of what i'm doing
If anyone can help .... :)[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved your problem, but leaving an answer here:

- restart VS Code
- restart the computer
- check about execution policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3#change-the-execution-policy